# How to split a month into number of weeks in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, date

For example, `Month = January 2021`

I want the expected outcome to be as shown below  with `format (dd-MM-yyyy)`

```
Week 1: 01-01-2021 -- 03-01-2021
Week 2: 04-01-2021 -- 10-01-2021
Week 3: 11-01-2021 -- 17-01-2021
Week 4: 18-01-2021 -- 24-01-2021
Week 5: 25-01-2021 -- 31-01-2021
```

Comment: Good job on giving input and expected out.   So you want weeks (Monday through Sunday) except the first and last partial weeks if they are partial.  What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate all days for the month, then group by the ISO week and get the start and end date for that week:

```
select to_char(min(t.dt), 'dd-mm-yyyy') as week_start, 
       to_char(max(t.dt), 'dd-mm-yyyy') as week_end
from generate_series(date '2021-01-01', date '2021-01-31', interval '1 day') as t(dt)
group by to_char(t.dt, 'iyyy-iw')
order by to_char(t.dt, 'iyyy-iw')
```

returns

```
week_start | week_end  
-----------+-----------
01-01-2021 | 03-01-2021
04-01-2021 | 10-01-2021
11-01-2021 | 17-01-2021
18-01-2021 | 24-01-2021
25-01-2021 | 31-01-2021
```